# How to stop a for loop (OpenCV)

Tags: opencv, memory-management, for-loop, memory-leaks, processing

I am using Processing (processing.org) for a project that requires face tracking. The problem now is that the program is going to run out of memory because of a for loop. I want to stop the loop or at least solve the problem of running out of memory. This is the code.

```
import hypermedia.video.*;
import java.awt.Rectangle;


OpenCV opencv;

// contrast/brightness values
int contrast_value    = 0;
int brightness_value  = 0;



void setup() {

size( 900, 600 );

opencv = new OpenCV( this );
opencv.capture( width, height );                   // open video stream
opencv.cascade( OpenCV.CASCADE_FRONTALFACE_ALT );  // load detection description, here-> front face detection : "haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml"


// print usage
println( "Drag mouse on X-axis inside this sketch window to change contrast" );
println( "Drag mouse on Y-axis inside this sketch window to change brightness" );

}


public void stop() {
    opencv.stop();
    super.stop();
}



void draw() {

// grab a new frame
// and convert to gray
opencv.read();
opencv.convert( GRAY );
opencv.contrast( contrast_value );
opencv.brightness( brightness_value );

// proceed detection
Rectangle[] faces = opencv.detect( 1.2, 2, OpenCV.HAAR_DO_CANNY_PRUNING, 40, 40 );

// display the image
image( opencv.image(), 0, 0 );

// draw face area(s)
noFill();
stroke(255,0,0);
for( int i=0; i<faces.length; i++ ) {
    rect( faces[i].x, faces[i].y, faces[i].width, faces[i].height ); 
}
}

void mouseDragged() {
contrast_value   = (int) map( mouseX, 0, width, -128, 128 );
brightness_value = (int) map( mouseY, 0, width, -128, 128 );
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: why and when you want to stop the loop?

Comment: for( int i=0; i<faces.length; i++ ) {
    rect( faces[i].x, faces[i].y, faces[i].width, faces[i].height ); 
}
That is the loop. I want to either stop it or release the memory that was previously taken since I will be running out of storage if it goes on. Then it would show a MemoryError after 20 seconds.

Comment: You might be running out of memory because of the resolution at which the images are analyzed. Try something smaller, like: `opencv.capture( 320, 240 );`. Even though the image is smaller, you can display it larger in the draw loop: `image( opencv.image(), 0, 0 width,height);`. It will just look a bit pixely. Also you might want to tick "Increase maximum available memory" and give it 512MB or something.

Comment: @GeorgeProfenza that would be better as answer, rather than as comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few points...

## 1 As George mentioned in the comments, you can reduce the size of the capture area, which will exponentially reduce the amount of RAM that your sketch is using to analyze the face tracking. Try making two global variables called CaptureWidth and CaptureHeight and set them to 320 and 240 - which is totally sufficient for this.

## 2 You can increase the amount of memory that your sketch uses by default in the Java Virtual Machine. Processing defaults to 128 I think, but if you go to the Preferences, you will see a checkbox to "Increase maximum available memory to [x]" ... I usually make mine 1500 mb, but it depends on your machine what you can handle. Dont try to make it bigger than 1800mb unless you are on a 64-bit machine and are using Processing 2.0 in 64-bit mode...

## 3 To actually break the loop... use the 'break' command http://processing.org/reference/break.html ... but please understand *why* you want to use that first, as this will simply jump you out of your loop.

## 4 If you only want to show a certain number of faces, you can test if faces[i] == 1, et cetera, which might help....

But I think the loop itself isn't the culprit here, it's more likely the memory footprint. Start with suggestions 1 & 2 and report back...